# Type Number data given in the input field is not stored inside the mongoDb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller

I am attempting to add 'price' and 'stock' values to a database where their type is set to 'Number.' When I console.log(req.body), I can see that the data is being received. However, these values are not being stored in the database, even though all other field data is successfully stored and displayed in the frontend.

I will share my product controller, product schema, and product EJS code below.

This is my **Product Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    productDescription: {
        type: String,
        // required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0, // Set a default value
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0, // Set a default value
    },
    quantityInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0, // Set a default value
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
    },
    subcategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Subcategory',
    },
    productImages: [String], // Array of URLs or file references
    weight: String,
    lastupdated: {
        type : Date ,
    },
    isAvailable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

module.exports = Product
```

This is my **Product Controller**

```
const addproduct = async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        console.log('hi')
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log(req.body.productPrice)

        // Parse productPrice and productStock as integers
        const productPrice = parseInt(req.body.productPrice, 10);
        const productStock = parseInt(req.body.productStock, 10);

        // Get product data from the form 
        const {
            productName,
            // productPrice,
            productDescription,
            // productStock,
            productStatus,
        } = req.body
console.log(req.body)
console.log(req.body.productPrice)

        // Create a new product document
        const newProduct = new Product({
            productName,
            productPrice,
            productDescription,
            productStock,
            productStatus
        })

        const validationError = newProduct.validateSync(); // Synchronous validation
if (validationError) {
    console.error(validationError);
    // Handle validation error (e.g., return an error response)
} else {
    // Save the new product to the database
    await newProduct.save();
    // Redirect to the product list page after adding the product 
    res.redirect('/admin/products')
}
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Internal Error')
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

this is my **Product ejs **

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="addProductModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="addProductModalLabel">Add Product</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- //enctype="multipart/form-data" -->
            <form  id="productForm" method="post" action="/admin/addproduct" > 
          <!-- Product Form Goes Here -->
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productName" class="form-label">Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" required>
                </div>
            
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productPrice" class="form-label">Price</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productDescription" class="form-label">Product Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="productDescription" name="productDescription" required></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productStock" class="form-label">Stock</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="productStock" name="productStock" required>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productImage" class="form-label">Product Image</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="productImage" name="productImage" accept="image/*" required>
                </div> -->
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="productStatus" class="form-label">Status</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="productStatus" name="productStatus" required>
                        <option value="active">Active</option>
                        <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Save Product</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried to console.log(req.body), and I can see that the data is being received. However, it is not being stored in the database. So, I suspect the issue may be related to assigning values from req.body to the variables.